# jQuery: update an object's image source

Tags: jquery, image

[On this sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/7bxhetvd/), I failed to update the source of the object (image):

```
var image = $('<img />');
image.src = 'http://placehold.it/350x150';
image.appendTo( $('#test') );
```

Comment: it's because image it's a jquery object and you need to use attr("","") to change/set the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image element is created via Jquery, `image` is a jquery object rather than a DOM element object. You should utilize jquery's attribute setter instead. see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements

```
var image = $('<img />');
image.attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/350x150');
image.appendTo($('#test'));
```

or even better, set the property when creating the element:

```
var image = $('<img />',{src:'http://placehold.it/350x150'});
image.appendTo($('#test'));
```